# Ninja forms - checkbox checked-value issue. Is it possible to modify? Calculation not working

Tags: php, checkbox, wordpress, genesis

I don't know if this is the correct place to ask, but I'll try. I have an ongoing project with Wordpress (Genesis framework - Agentpress PRO theme) working with Ninja Forms, and am having a slight problem. The web page is: http://www.supercastor.net/wordpress/listings/castellon-65-m2-ytong/

I have a listings page (for each house model). Each listing has metadata that is accessible via a simple function from the genesis framework:

```
genesis_get_custom_field( 'CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME' );
```

I would like to have, like the link above has, a list of checkboxes that the user can select/deselect, and the TOTAL value is finally calculated. Everything is working, except that I cannot assign the value of this "custom field" that is from the listing.

I am using Ninja Forms, and after some research, I have come up with the solution of registering a custom field in NF:

```
function precio_basico_calc_display( $field_id, $data ){

    // Get the default_value
    if( isset( $data['default_value'] ) ){
    $def_value_new = genesis_get_custom_field( '_listing_precio_sort' );
    $data['default_value'] = $def_value_new;
        $default_value = $data['default_value'];
    debug_to_console("Default_value is set to:$default_value");
    }else{
        $default_value = '';
    debug_to_console("Default_value NOT SET");
    }

    $products_select = genesis_get_custom_field( '_listing_precio_sort' );
    }

    // Now that $products_select is populated with the listing_price, output a checkbox with the value of the price. ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ninja_forms_field_<?php echo $field_id;?>" value="<?php echo $products_select;?>" checked="checked" class="ninja-forms-field ninja-forms-field-calc-listen" disabled="disabled">
    <?php
}
```

I also have a small "debug_to_console" function, but this is just as a quick "debugging". I can see that the value is there, but in the calculation it is not set. I have set the default to 40.000, but it should be set to the value for each price (in the link example, should be 19.000). As:

```
$products_select = genesis_get_custom_field( '_listing_precio_sort' );
```

And I have also tried the following (field_id 33 is the checkbox in the form):

```
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_field', 'my_filter_function', 10, 2 );

function my_filter_function( $data, $field_id ){
    if( $field_id == 33 ){
        $listing_price = genesis_get_custom_field( '_listing_precio_sort' );
        $data['default_value'] = $listing_price;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

But it isn't working either. I mean, it does display the value (in the console), but not making the calculation correctly.

Help! I just want the calculation (TOTAL) to update correctly for each listing. I thought changing the default_value would do, but it doesn't. I'm lost :(

Thanks!

Comment: Long description, if you can summarize better at the end, might be easier to help. Also, `if( $field_id == 31 || $field_id == 31 ){` does not make any sense. When is this true?

Comment: @Twisty I tried reducing the description. Just didn't want to leave anything out. Also the field_id thing. What I wanted is to just be able to correctly calculate the TOTAL (once the checkbox is checked/unchecked). Thanks